# Block web sites for VPN clients

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, vpn, ipsec

I installed IPSEC L2TP VPN Server on Ubuntu 12 x86 vps machine. I want to block some web sites for clients connected to VPN Server. So, changed hosts file in Ubuntu to block accessing unwanted web sites like that:
0.0.0.0 www.unwanteddomain.com etc.

When I try to connect unwanted web sites from terminal in Ubuntu with **wget www.unwanteddomain.com** it says:

> Resolving www.unwanteddomain.com (www.unwanteddomain.com)... 0.0.0.0
>   Connecting to www.unwanteddomain.com (www.unwanteddomain.com)|0.0.0.0|:80... failed: Connection refused.

So I think hosts file function works well. But when I want to open these web sites from connected VPN Clients, it doesn't work. I can still access all web sites from client.

How is it possible that while VPN Server cannot access a site, VPN Client can? And what must I do to block these sites from also VPN Clients?

**IPTables.rules**

```
    filter
    :INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
    :FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
    :OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
    :ICMPALL - [0:0]
    -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
    -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
    -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
    -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 255 -j ICMPALL
    -A INPUT -p udp --dport 67:68 --sport 67:68 -j ACCEPT
    -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
    -A INPUT -p udp -m multiport --dports 500,4500 -j ACCEPT
    -A INPUT -p udp --dport 1701 -m policy --dir in --pol ipsec -j ACCEPT
    -A INPUT -p udp --dport 1701 -j DROP
    -A INPUT -j DROP
    -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
    -A FORWARD -i eth+ -o ppp+ -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
    -A FORWARD -i ppp+ -o eth+ -j ACCEPT
    -A FORWARD -j DROP
    -A ICMPALL -p icmp -f -j DROP        
    -A ICMPALL -p icmp --icmp-type 0 -j ACCEPT
    -A ICMPALL -p icmp --icmp-type 3 -j ACCEPT
    -A ICMPALL -p icmp --icmp-type 4 -j ACCEPT
    -A ICMPALL -p icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
    - A ICMPALL -p icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT
    -A ICMPALL -p icmp -j DROP
    COMMIT
    *nat
    :PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
    :INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
    :OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
    :POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
    -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.42.0/24 -o eth+ -j SNAT --to-source 23.x.x.203
    COMMIT
```

Comment: Using the hosts file is a horrible way to block a website.  Why don't you just configure the DNS of the VPN in such a way it cannot resolve those domains?

Comment: How can I configure DNS in Ubuntu? I have known that it could be with the hosts file.

Comment: You can run your DNS service if you want.  What have you tried?

Comment: In fact, nothing for DNS service. But I wonder how is it possible VPN client access web page while VPN server cannot access. I'm not sure about that VPN clients will not access if I install DNS service, will they?